# What is the function _transformer_encoder_layer_fwd in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, transformer-model

I ran into the `function _transformer_encoder_layer_fwd` of PyTorch in the `lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/_C/_VariableFunctions.pyi` file, [the function is called here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaI5I.png).

But I didn't find any details about this function. Why could this function be called? And how?

```
def _transformer_encoder_layer_fwd(src: Tensor, embed_dim:
                                   _int, num_heads: _int,
                                   qkv_weight: Tensor,
                                   qkv_bias: Tensor,
                                   proj_weight: Tensor,
                                   proj_bias: Tensor,
                                   use_gelu: _bool,
                                   norm_first: _bool,
                                   eps: _float,
                                   norm_weight_1: Tensor,
                                   norm_bias_1: Tensor,
                                   norm_weight_2: Tensor,
                                   norm_bias_2: Tensor,
                                   ffn_weight_1: Tensor,
                                   ffn_bias_1: Tensor,
                                   ffn_weight_2: Tensor,
                                   ffn_bias_2: Tensor,
                                   mask: Optional[Tensor] = None,
                                   mask_type: Optional[_int] = None) -> Tensor:
```

...

The function is defined in `torch/_C/_VariableFunctions.pyi`

I tried to find any details of this function about how this function be called. But no results.

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.TransformerEncoderLayer.html) in the "Fast path" section, the forward() method of nn.TransformerEncoderLayer can make use of [Flash Attention](https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.14135), which is an optimized self-attention implementation using fused operations. However there are a bunch of criteria that must be satisfied for flash attention to be used, as described in the PyTorch documentation.

From the implementation on the Transformer encoder [on PyTorch's GitHub](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/nn/modules/transformer.py#L697), this method call is likely where Flash Attention is applied.